# How to add custom translation object on Promotion

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, localization, mariadb, sylius

I want to translate the Promotions entities in Sylius. I followed what is proposed in this issue: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/8695

I was thus successful in accessing the add/modify forms in the administration part of Sylius. However, as soon as I submit the form, I get an error that occurs:
Return value of App\Entity\Promotion\Promotion::getTranslations() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, null returned

After analysis, it seems that the link between the $translations variable of the Promotion entity, added using the TranslatableTrait, is not correctly linked with the $translatable variable of the PromotionTranslate entity.

Anyone know how to resolve this?
I tried to add Doctrine annotations on the $translations but it leads to other problems later.

I'm using Sylius 1.10.4, and PHP 7.4.

Here is my code:

```
# src/entity/PromotionTranslations.php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_promotion")
 */
class Promotion extends BasePromotion implements ResourceInterface, TranslatableInterface
{
    use TranslatableTrait {
        TranslatableTrait::__construct as private initializeTranslationsCollection;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->initializeTranslationsCollection();
    }
    protected function createTranslation(): PromotionTranslationInterface
    {
        return new PromotionTranslation();
    }
}
```

```
# src/entity/PromotionTranslations.php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_promotion_translation")
 */
class PromotionTranslation extends AbstractTranslation implements PromotionTranslationInterface, TranslationInterface, ResourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

```
# src/Form/Extension/Promotion/PromotionTypeExtension.php

final class PromotionTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    private $channelContext;

    public function __construct(ChannelContextInterface $channelContext)
    {
        $this->channelContext = $channelContext;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $options['data']->getChannels()[] = $this->channelContext->getChannel();
        $builder
            ->add('translations', ResourceTranslationsType::class, [
                'entry_type' => PromotionTranslationType::class,
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [PromotionType::class];
    }
}
```

```
# config/packages/sylius_resource.yaml
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.promotion:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            classes:
                model: App\Entity\Promotion\Promotion
            translation:
                classes:
                    model: App\Entity\Promotion\PromotionTranslation
```

Comment: Try adding the forms to the resource config as shown here: https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/cookbook/entities/custom-translatable-model.html#register-the-forms-as-resource-forms-of-the-supplier-entity

Comment: Nope, it does not work better with specified forms in resource config.

Comment: I can't see any issues in the code and config you shared. Can you reproduce it in a repository with all the elements and share it?